# Функция 'turn' выполняется только для последнего 'cell'. Как сделать для каждого 'cell'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Функция 'turn' выполняется только для последнего 'cell'. Как сделать для каждого 'cell'.

```
root = Tk()


def turn(event):
    cell["text"] = "1"



for x in range(8):
    for y in range(8):
        cell = Label(root, width=3, height=1, text=".")
        cell.grid(row=x, column=y)
        cell.bind("<Button-1>", turn)



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помимо варианта [@gil9red](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/834649/255866) могу предложить этот вариант через `event.widget["text"]`

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()


def turn(event):
    event.widget["text"] = 1

for x in range(8):
    for y in range(8):
        cell = Label(root, width=3, height=1, text=".")
        cell.grid(row=x, column=y)
        cell.bind("<Button-1>", turn)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте:

```
def turn(cell, event):
    cell["text"] = "1"

...

cell.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, cell=cell: turn(cell, event))
```

Comment: странно, но по сути он от примера никак не отличается :D. Я только когда у себя проверил заметил

Comment: @Twiss, ваш вариант лучше :)